Unicode character cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range of 0 to 255
I work with spring boot, angular 7 ,tomcat 9.
I have this code in order to upload file :
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadMultipleFiles/{uid}")
    public List<UploadFile> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files,@PathVariable String uid) {
    
        return Arrays.asList(files)
                .stream()
                .map(file -> uploadFile(file,uid))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    

   @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile/{uuid}")
    public UploadFile uploadFile(@RequestParam("files")  MultipartFile files,@PathVariable String uuid) {
         try {
            
             fileStorageProperties.setUploadDir("D:/"+uuid);
             fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()) ;
             Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
                this.fileStorageService = new FileStorageService(this.fileStorageProperties);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the direeectory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
            }
        String fileName = this.fileStorageService.storeFile(files);

        
        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/api/upload-files/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();

        return new UploadFile(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                files.getContentType(), String.valueOf(files.getSize()));
    }

in the server I have this error :
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse The HTTP response header [X-app-params] with value [777sssd99999E7E6FBD11234569882202518159070/قرار تشكيل وحدة التجارب.pdf] has been removed from the response because it is invalid
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unicode character [ق] at code point [1,602] cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range of 0 to 255
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.toBytesSimple(MessageBytes.java:292)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.toBytes(MessageBytes.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.write(Http11OutputBuffer.java:394)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.sendHeader(Http11OutputBuffer.java:372)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1065)

I think that this error is related to utf8 encoding.
I try without success to enable utf8 in tomcat by adding :
server.xml :
  <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="655360" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="-1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />

web.xml :
   <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    
    
      <mime-mapping>
<extension>html</extension>
<mime-type>text/html;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
<extension>js</extension>
<mime-type>text/javascript;charset=utf-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

also I try without success with :
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile/{uuid}")
    public UploadFile uploadFile(@RequestParam("files")  MultipartFile files,@PathVariable String uuid) {
         try {
        
             fileStorageProperties.setUploadDir("D:/"+uuid);
             fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()) ;;
             Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
                this.fileStorageService = new FileStorageService(this.fileStorageProperties);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the direeectory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
            }
        String fileName = this.fileStorageService.storeFile(files);

        try {
            fileName = new String(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/api/upload-files/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();

        return new UploadFile(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                files.getContentType(), String.valueOf(files.getSize()));
    }

